# Change of basis between $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) $

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, change-of-basis

As number fields, we have that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3})\simeq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) $ however we can write the elements different says:

\begin{eqnarray*}
x &=& a + b(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) +  c(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^ 2 + d(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^3\\
&\text{or}& \\
x &=& a + b \sqrt{2} + c \sqrt{3} + d \sqrt{6}
\end{eqnarray*}

It's not instantly obvious to me that $\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ but I'm sure it' s the case...

What is the change of basis between one and the other?  Maybe that way we can find the linear combination... I' d like the change of basis in order toshow:

$$ \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3} = a + b\big(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\big) +  c\big(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\big)^ 2 + d\big(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\big)^3 $$

Comment: Multiply $\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}$ by $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$. That shows that it is an element of ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$. To express it in the basis, you now need to express $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}}$ in that basis. Can you do that?

Comment: @Magdiragdag You're right: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}} = -(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ we'd need the minimal polynomial of $x = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$... this amounts to fishing around for relations.  We' re going to do that anyway. A change of basis matrix could be more systematic.

Answer (score 4):

These scratchworks easily turn into an answer:

\begin{eqnarray*}
1 &=& 1\\
\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} &=& 1 \cdot \sqrt{2} + 1 \cdot \sqrt{3} \\
(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^2 &=& 5 \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot \sqrt{6} \\
(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^3 &=&  11 \cdot \sqrt{2} + 5 \cdot \sqrt{3}
\end{eqnarray*}

and we can get a change of basis matrix finally (as a matrix over $\mathbb{Q})$:

$$\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
5 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 11 & 5 & 0  \end{array}\right]\;
\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ \sqrt{2} \\ \sqrt{3} \\ \sqrt{6}\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
\;\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}\;\\
(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^2 \\
(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^3 \end{array} \right]$$

Incidentally I noticed that $\cos 15^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{6}- \sqrt{2}}{4} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) \simeq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})$ using the difference of angles formula.